Adata hardcoded in CCM
I have a situation in which Adata is hardcoded in AES CCM mode of operations at encryption side and this data is transferred through internet. I know that we can have Adata as an empty string (NIST document), but what will be the impact of hardcoded Adata on overall AES CCM scheme.

This apply generally to all AEAD ciphers. Adata are like headers of a data packet, hard-coding it is like hard-coding the IP address of a web server in a client program.

i know this, Adata does not contain any information its only have random data. its just it is hardcoded for each encryption process. Does this actually have any impact on confidentially of CCM scheme?

@tester11 No. Fixed Adata doesn't affect confidentiality of CCM, or any AEAD cipher in general.

thanks. can you provide some reference material for further study on AEAD ciphers?

@tester11 Can't think of a good one, but here it goes: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5116
